# Sum total of report column

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I try to sum the total of a column of my report based on `=ReportItems!Textbox135.Value`

This field is not included in the dataset, but is a textfield in the report. I use the following expression in the group header of my report

```
=SUM(ReportItems!Textbox135.Value)
```

Which results in the error:

```
Aggregate functions can be used only on report items contained in page headers and footers
```

What is the correct expression to sum report items?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
=SUM(Fields!YourField.Value)
```

Comment: The field is not part of the dataset.

Comment: It helps to include that information in your question.