# Sum column of report items

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

When the following `IIF` expression is true, the row gets a 1 and if false the row gets a 0.

```
=IIF(Fields!MatchField.Value = "No match" and Fields!X.Value >= 1000, 1, 0)
```

What I want is to calculate the total sum of the column. If I use the same expression in the column group, the sum is always 0. If I use the textbox  value of the row like this:

```
=SUM(ReportItems!Textbox41.Value)
```

The report returns an error:

> Aggregate functions can be used only on report items contained in page headers and footers

**Update #1**

I implemented the solution from the link in Kavin's answer, but every total_sum is still 0.

```
Public Total_lookup_Sum As Integer = 0 

Public Function Lookup_Sum(ByVal value As Integer) As Integer

    Total_lookup_Sum = Total_lookup_Sum + value    

 Return value 

End Function
```

Comment: [link](https://ashwaniashwin.wordpress.com/2014/01/23/aggregate-functions-can-be-used-only-on-report-items-contained-in-page-headers-and-footers-using-aggregate-on-aggregate-function-in-expression/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sum total of report column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30480345/sum-total-of-report-column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue tby adding a calculated field (name:testField) to the dataset with the expression:

```
=IIF(Fields!MatchField.Value = "No match" and Fields!X.Value >= 1000, 1, 0)
```

After this you can easily sum the total:

```
=SUM[testField]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the Following Given in this Link:

[Forum 1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/002c459a-2260-437a-a53c-a380bc2299d0/sum-column-gives-error-aggregate-functions-can-be-used-only-on-report-items-contained-in-page?forum=sqlreportingservices)
[Forum 2](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2972/sql-server-reporting-services-reportitems-collection/)

or

Try This:

```
=SUM(Fields!YourField.Value)
```

Comment: I tried the solutions mentioned on the fora, but the result of the totals is still 0

Comment: Check out with this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30480345/sum-total-of-report-column?rq=1   Which u got solution earlier